# GNU Make how to make a static pattern rule for files that are not in the same directory?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I want to use `make` and create a static pattern rule that has the target in a `output` directory, and the prerequisite files are in the preceeding directory, and it has to work recursively.

I have a minimal example here:

```
.
├── anotherdir
│   ├── output
│   │   ├── source3.md
│   │   └── source4.md
│   ├── source3.json
│   └── source4.json
├── output
│   ├── source1.md
│   └── source2.md
├── source1.json
└── source2.json
```

I want to generate the `output` directories if they do not exist, and I want to generate `*.md` files from the `*.json` using `make` if they do not exist, or `*.json` is updated.

So far, I have the following `Makefile`:

```
SOURCE_FILES := $(shell find ./ -name "*.json")
OUTPUT_FILES := $(join $(addsuffix output/,$(dir $(SOURCE_FILES))), $(addsuffix .md,$(basename $(notdir $(SOURCE_FILES)))))

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUT_FILES)

$(OUTPUT_FILES): %.md: %.json
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    # Command to create MD file from json file into the output directory here
```

The actual command to create the MD file from the json file doesn't matter here, because I have a script that I will call that will do this for me. The problem here, is that when I try to even run this at all, I get the following output:

```
> make all
make: *** No rule to make target 'anotherdir/output/source4.json', needed by 'anotherdir/output/source4.md'.  Stop.
```

Obviously, `source4.json` is not in `anotherdir/output`, but rather, it's in the preceeding directory, which is just `anotherdir`. I don't know how to make it so that the pattern `$(OUTPUT_FILES): %.md: %.json` will match it properly.

Or is a static pattern rule not good here? I'm not sure what to do to fit my scenario.

EDIT: I tried to do something like this:

```
$(OUTPUT_FILES): %.md: $(join $(subst output,,$(dir %)), $(addsuffix .json,$(basename $(notdir %))))
```

and this doesn't work, I still get:

```
> make all
make: *** No rule to make target 'anotherdir/output/source4.json', needed by 'anotherdir/output/source4.md'.  Stop.
```

Edit 2: to clarify, i start with the following files

```
.
├── anotherdir
│   ├── source3.json
│   └── source4.json
├── source1.json
└── source2.json
```

And then when i run make, i want it to generate the output folders like this

```
.
├── anotherdir
│   ├── output
│   │   ├── source3.md
│   │   └── source4.md
│   ├── source3.json
│   └── source4.json
├── output
│   ├── source1.md
│   └── source2.md
├── source1.json
└── source2.json
```

I want to use some kind of smart makefile syntax to pick up these files names without me hard coding it in myself. Hence, i looked at the documentation and saw that static pattern rules might be the solution that i want, except that i can't get the right prerequisite pattern down.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that it has to work recursively?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think recursively was a good choice of words there. I meant that it has to work on all json files in the directory and subdirectory, not just the json files located in the same location as the Makefile. I kinda already got this by using the find command, so now i just need to generate the md files into the output folder that is relative to each of the json file. So in the above post, imagine all the output folders not generated yet. When i run make, i want all of those output folders to be generated along with the corresponding md file from the json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it had not been proposed already in another answer I would have suggested `foreach-eval-call`. For completeness here are different solutions for GNU make (they may work also with other versions of make but I did not check):

### Creating the output directories beforehand

If the output directories exist already you can refer to `../%.json` in your pattern rule:

```
SOURCE_FILES := $(shell find . -name "*.json")
OUTPUT_FILES := $(join $(dir $(SOURCE_FILES)),\
    $(patsubst %.json,output/%.md,$(notdir $(SOURCE_FILES))))
$(shell mkdir -p $(dir $(OUTPUT_FILES)))

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUT_FILES)

%.md: ../%.json
    : json2md $< -o $@
```

This may look strange but if you read carefully the [Pattern match section of the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) you should quickly understand. The only constraint for this to work is that the output directories exist before make searches pattern rules that match the targets. If one does not exist make will complain that there is no eligible rule to build the target. This is the reason for the:

```
$(shell mkdir -p $(dir $(OUTPUT_FILES)))
```

at the beginning of the Makefile. Demonstration:

```
$ make
: json2md output/../source2.json -o output/source2.md
: json2md output/../source1.json -o output/source1.md
: json2md anotherdir/output/../source4.json -o anotherdir/output/source4.md
: json2md anotherdir/output/../source3.json -o anotherdir/output/source3.md
```

### Using the [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion)

Secondary expansion gives you the possibility to use automatic variables in the list of prerequisites. The `$$` are needed to escape the first expansion by make.

```
SOURCE_FILES := $(shell find . -name "*.json")
OUTPUT_FILES := $(join $(dir $(SOURCE_FILES)),\
    $(patsubst %.json,output/%.md,$(notdir $(SOURCE_FILES))))

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUT_FILES)

$(sort $(dir $(OUTPUT_FILES))):
    mkdir -p $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OUTPUT_FILES): $$(patsubst %output,%,$$(@D))$$(basename $$(@F)).json | $$(dir $$@)
    : json2md $< -o $@
```

Demonstration:

```
$ make
mkdir -p output/
mkdir -p anotherdir/output/
: json2md source2.json -o output/source2.md
: json2md source1.json -o output/source1.md
: json2md anotherdir/source4.json -o anotherdir/output/source4.md
: json2md anotherdir/source3.json -o anotherdir/output/source3.md
```

> Note: instead of creating the output directories in the json-to-md rule (which has the drawback of creating them several times), I added them as [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) and added a specific rule to create them.
>
> Note: the `sort` function also removes duplicates.

### Using recursive make

Here we invoke make (with always the same Makefile) recursively in each sub-directory (except `output`, of course). Each invocation handles only the local json files, which makes the paths of prerequisites and targets much simpler.

```
MF           := $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
SUB_DIRS     := $(filter-out . ./output,$(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -type d))
SOURCE_FILES := $(filter-out $(SUB_DIRS),$(wildcard *.json))
OUTPUT_FILES := $(patsubst %.json,output/%.md,$(SOURCE_FILES))

.PHONY: $(SUB_DIRS) all
all: $(SUB_DIRS) $(OUTPUT_FILES)

$(OUTPUT_FILES): output/%.md: %.json | output
    : json2md $< -o $@

output:
    mkdir -p $@

$(SUB_DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ -f $(MF)
```

Demonstration:

```
$ make
make -C anotherdir -f /home/doe/json2md/Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/doe/json2md/anotherdir'
mkdir -p output
: json2md source4.json -o output/source4.md
: json2md source3.json -o output/source3.md
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/doe/json2md/anotherdir'
mkdir -p output
: json2md source2.json -o output/source2.md
: json2md source1.json -o output/source1.md
```

Comment: I really like the first solution here, makes it more simple and easier to understand, without losing too much of clarity.

Comment: Trying to understand the SECONDEXPANSION solution with the order prerequisite. Is this a typo? Shouldn't it be: `$$(dir $$@)` instead of `$$(dir $$@D)`

Comment: Ooops, yes, you are right, it is `$$(dir $$@)`. I fixed my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it this way:

First, find the source files just as you did (with a small change to prevent the unsightly double-slash):

```
SOURCE_FILES := $(shell find . -name "*.json")
```

A pattern file would be nice, if we could use two wildcards at once, but Make can't quite do that. So I recommend using a template:

```
define template
TDIR := $(dir $(1))output
TARG := $$(TDIR)/$(notdir $(basename $(1))).md
$$(TARG): $(1)
    mkdir -p $$@
    @echo building $$@ from $$<
    # Command to create MD file from json file into the output directory here
endef

$(foreach SOURCE,$(SOURCE_FILES),$(eval $(call template,$(SOURCE))))
```

If this works, all that's left is to construct a list of output files, and a default rule that has all of them as prerequisites:

```
define template
TDIR := $(dir $(1))output
TARG := $$(TDIR)/$(notdir $(basename $(1))).md
OUTPUT_FILES += $$(TARG)
$$(TARG): $(1)
    mkdir -p $$@
    @echo building $$@ from $$<
    # Command to create MD file from json file into the output directory here
endef

all:

$(foreach SOURCE,$(SOURCE_FILES),$(eval $(call template,$(SOURCE))))

all: $(OUTPUT_FILES)
```

It isn't pretty, but it seems to work.